# Android Studio Notification: How to run notification ONLY when the data is changed on the Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase

In my android app, I use Firebase real-time database to update the data changes and display on my screen.

```
  @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        userReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot userData) {

                userStarredMatchList.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot userDataSnapshot : userData.getChildren()) {


                notificationFunction();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { /* BLANK */}

        });

    }
```

I do something like this, so that it runs whenever the data is updated on the reference. The `notificationFunction()` runs when the data is updated, but the problem is it runs whenever I get on this screen and return to the screen.

How can I make it NOT to run whenever I refresh the screen? (Make it run ONLY when the data is changed).

Comment: You can add this code in your main activity which gets open 1st after you open the app, and then send this Firebase data to whichever classes you want using setter methods.

Comment: But wouldn't it still run when the app first starts, which is what I don't want ?

Comment: Yeah it would on app open.. you can read about `childEventListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move your code somewhere in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the functionality as an RxJava Observable and then filter it using the skip operator in order to skip the first event.

Off the top of my head:

```
Observable<DataSnapshot> o = Observable.create(emitter -> {

    userReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot userData) {

            userStarredMatchList.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot userDataSnapshot : userData.getChildren()) {


                emitter.onNext(userDataSnapshot);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { /* BLANK */}

    });


}).skip(1);
```

You can then subscribe to it in `onStart()` and display your notification.

Comment: Will this only skip the first round?

Comment: Yeah so essentially each time your code in the OP is ran, when the screen refreshes etc., it will run once then wait for data changes.  This code will skip the time when it just runs initially.